# Asp.Net MVC Controller and View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a controller, that returns an image.

In my view, i have:

```
@model MyShop.Models.Car
....
<img src="@Url.Action("myimage", "Image", new { code = model.Code, imageFile = model.imageFile })" class="img-responsive">
```

I have an error because model is not defined.
If I use

```
 @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
```

It works fine. 
How can I reference the current item in the first snippet?

Thanks

Comment: Try `Model` with a capital M. That will access the view's Model property, as opposed to the lambda variable used in `DisplayFor`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return in model image path also where your image in your project.

```
 <img src= "@Url.Content(Model.ImagePath)" alt="Image" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: change `model.Code` to `Model.Code`

```
<img src="@Url.Action("myimage", "Image", new { code = Model.Code, imageFile = Model.imageFile })" class="img-responsive">
```

or if you're have complete image path in `imageFile` then try:

```
<img  src="@Model.imageFile" alt="your image" class="img-responsive"/>
```